# remove only vertical cell spacing from html table

Tags: html, css

I am working on my website and have drawn up how I wish to display my pricing info. putting it all into the table is easy enough, and i have found most of the initial questions. i have a border on the left, right and bottom of each  tag, which line up with the top 3  nicely and similar to my drawing. the only question I have is to remove the cellspacing from only the top or bottom of each row. i tried using the collapse cell code which works great, except, then it eliminates the border-radius i wish to have. Ideas?

PICTURE
https://www.dropbox.com/sc/j2k1wh8ar5girwl/fcp52qP03n

CODE
https://www.dropbox.com/s/h3605tq9dhq5475/test.txt

Comment: Please show your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**USE THIS:**

```
table, td, th  {
border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Sample **AFTER**: http://jsfiddle.net/theStudent/N2w3N/

Sample **BEFORE**: http://jsfiddle.net/theStudent/FJ69C/

Hows this one: http://jsfiddle.net/theStudent/N2w3N/1/

Comment: is there anyway to use border-collapse and still round the top on the top row <td>'s?

Comment: Ohh sorry missed that part in the question, let me attempt it :)

Comment: might another table stacked on-top work?

Comment: check out the last one is that good

Comment: i should still be able to remove the border from the first cell right? i'll look into it. thanks!